# Using gotoSlide function in Veeva CRM iRep

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe, adobe-edge

I use Adobe Edge to create sites. I need to use buttons and veeva:gotoSlide function to navigate through slides but buttons are not responding. I've tried using key message, presentation slide names as parameter but still couldn't figure it out.

My JS code is like this:

```
(function (symbolName) {
    Symbol.bindElementAction(
        compId,
        symbolName,
        "${next_btn}",
        "click",
        function () {
            document.location = "veeva:gotoSlide(CPS-000000007)";
        }
    );

    //Edge binding end
    Symbol.bindElementAction(
        compId,
        symbolName,
        "${prev_btn}",
        "click",
        function (sym, e) {
            veeva:gotoSlide(001);
        }
    );
})
```

Answer (score 5):

In Veeva each slide is associated to a key message, which in turn contains a media file. Each media file is a .zip file and can contain images, video, pdfs, of html pages. Finally, slides are associated to presentations; presentations may have a `presentation id`.

`gotoSlide` can be used to jump around slides into presentations and also to jump to slides of other presentations. `gotoSlide` takes one or two parametes that are:

- `media file`, mandatory, which is the name of the file that contains the media (e.g. `intro.zip` in the example below)
- `presentation id`, optional, which is the id of the presentation that contains the media (e.g. `myProductBenefits` in the example below)

## Example

For simplicity, let's assume that each key message is directly associated to a presentation. Let's say that we have three key messages (I'm making up names, just to be clear):

1. **Introduction**, that contains the file `intro.zip`
2. **Benefits**, that contains `my_benefits.zip`
3. **Why switch**, that contains `whySwitch.zip`

key messages 1. and 2. are associated to a presentation called **Benfits of myProduct** which has `presentation_id = myProductBenefits`, while 3. is not associated.

It is possible to jump to slides with the following links:

1. `veeva:gotoSlide(intro.zip)`
2. `veeva:gotoSlide(my_benefits.zip)`
3. `veeva:gotoSlide(intro.zip, myProductBenefits)`
4. `veeva:gotoSlide(my_benefits.zip, myProductBenefits)`
5. `veeva:gotoSlide(whySwitch.zip, myProductBenefits)`

Note that:

- parameters are **NOT** quoted (`intro.zip` and **NOT** `'intro.zip'`)
- the second parameter is optional. If it is not provided, Veeva will only jump to slides that are inside the current presentation (it is **NOT** possible to jump to `veeva:gotoSlide(whySwitch.zip)` because **Why switch** key message is **NOT** associated with **Benfits of myProduct** presentation)
- in Veeva the `presentation_id` is under `migration`, even if the presentation was not migrated (it's a little bit misleading)
- the links works both in Javascript `window.location = "veeva:gotoSlide(intro.zip)";` and in HTML `<a href="veeva:gotoSlide(intro.zip)">Go to introduction</a>`

Comment: Is it possible to add back button just like in browsers back button, which goes to previous slide where it was come from?

Comment: @endo64 - Veeva CRM includes buttons to go back to previous slides by default in their interface.

Comment: @LisaCerilli But if you come to a pageA from pageX OR pageY (by clicking an image or link on those pages) Veeva CRM's back button will not take you back to the page where you come from. It just takes you prev. and next page in a sequential order.

Comment: @endo Just tried it on a project now. I started on the first slide, then from the menu clicked on the last slide. The menu gave an arrow that brought be back to the first slide. Then I went to the middle slide. The back button brought me to the last slide, then the first slide.

The back button brings you to the slide you were on last, and the next button (which only shows up if you use the back button) brings you to the slide you were on before if you used the back button. It works just like the previous/next in web browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much @LisaCerilli I didn't know that it works like that (or it wasn't when I tried) Thanks!